# Sandbox solution length to long causes 'An unexpected error has occurred.'

Tags: web-part

I have a webpart where users are able to enter a large amount of string into a textbox.

When the users enter something around 60,000+, the webpart throws a

`Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.`

I can't debug this either because when I click the button, the trace stops before it even goes to the event caller.

Comment: you got this error, once you have added  60,000+ in multiple textbox within your web part and click submit ? right ? should you check the server memory consume  when you try to do this ? also what's the memory specification of your server ?

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue?

https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/character-limit-of-a-text-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the behavior that you have described in your question , I think the issue root cause is

1. The size of HTTP header request.
2. There is not available server memory.

**For the first reason:**

Check [Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper’s Execute method in the partial trust app domain](https://richardstk.com/2012/01/17/unhandled-exception-was-thrown-by-the-sandboxed-code-wrappers-execute-method-in-the-partial-trust-app-domain/)

**For the second reason:**

If you checked [TextBox.MaxLength Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find When this property is set to 0, the maximum length of the text that can be entered in the control is **limited only by available memory**.

So, try to check your memory consume, during executing your code to make sure that this is the main issue, and based on this action , you should do the following to release all the leaked memory and consumed memory ! by

- Restart Sharepoint search host controller.
- Check the services that consume the memory , and stop it if it's not used
- Avoid configuring services application that not needed.

The above steps are temporary solutions , and you should `Scale up the memory` especially in production environment.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Administrative access, but testing on my VM, memory was the issue. I personally fixed the issue by making a json file for the solution to read from.